# Leap motion controller setTimeout Javascript scoring inaccurate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried numerous ways to try and do this without any success! at the moment with the existing code, when the user hovers 5 fingers over the leap motion controller, after 5seconds, the counter will start to count up continuously until it reaches up to 169 or something, I want it to just add up to 1. I am trying to get the user to hover over the leap motion 10 times, so each time the user does the exercise it adds 1 to a score so 1 / 10, then 2 / 10 and so forth. but when the user does it once I am getting 169 / 10! Has anybody got any suggestions on this or could point me in the right direction?! its for a college project and I feel out of my depth here! I have included all of the code:

```
//Set up the controller
var controller = new Leap.Controller();
var isCounting = false;
controller.on( 'frame' , function(frame){
  c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  var numberOfFingers = frame.fingers.length;
  c.font = "200px Arial";
  c.fillStyle = '#3e8a41';
  c.textAlign = 'center';
  c.textBaseline = 'middle';
  c.fillText( numberOfFingers , width/2 , height/2 );

  if(numberOfFingers == 5 && !isCounting) {
    isCounting = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      isCountring = false;
      if(numberOfFingers == 5){ //5 fingers still after 5s
        var start = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').innerHTML);
        var end = start+1;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = end;
        }
      }, 5*1000); //your 5s
    }
});


controller.connect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `frame` already runs really quickly, so you create a lot of setTimeouts and each adds 1 to your value. I suggest you set a flag to keep track of what you're doing:

```
var isCounting = false;
controller.on( 'frame' , function(frame){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    var numberOfFingers = frame.fingers.length;

    if(numberOfFingers == 5 && !isCounting) {
        isCounting = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            isCountring = false;
            if(numberOfFingers == 5){ //5 fingers still after 5s
                var start = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').innerHTML);
                var end = start+1;
                document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = end;
            }
        }, 5*1000); //your 5s 
     }
});
```

I don't own a leap so I can't be sure 100% but it's worth trying.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, this didn't work... it causes the canvas to disappear, is this because the controller.on( 'frame' , function(frame) is being repeated? or do you mean for me to include that within the above code? thanks again!

Comment: You need to merge my code into yours (just add all the lines that have an isCounting)

Comment: sorry had a bit of brain lapse then! so it works in that it counts to 1 after 5seconds, but then when you try and do it again it doesn't increase to 2, so it just sticks at 1 out of 10. is there a way to keep increasing by 1 each time?

Comment: I tried to recreate the situation without having a leap: http://jsfiddle.net/hyLLX/1/ the mousedown on the document would be your five fingers. It seems to work

Comment: I have updated the question code above including your code, I don't know why it stops after just one, the only difference is that you are also using setInterval in your jsfiddle?

Comment: The problem might be that both me and you have a typo in the code, on one line we write isCountring instad of isCounting. The setInterval in my code is just to simulate your leap running that function

Comment: ah thats it! as simple as that, didn't notice at all, it works perfectly thanks a lot for all of your help!